# reading from file error java

Tags: java, java-io

I use the code below to read from txt file.

```
ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.txt"));
//in.close();
while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
    elements.add(line);
}
check1 = (elements.get( 0));
System.out.println("HEYAAA \n" + check1);
//GUIServer guiServer = new GUIServer();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

I have "1. my name is bob \n 2. help you \n 3. Just testing" inside of txt file all on one line.. But when I read it into java it prints all in one line and doesn't read "\n".. how can I do it so it prints out on 3 lines so it reads the "\n" ..?

Alternatively I can separate them manually on txt file each on new lines, but how can I read for example, 3 lines and store into one variable..?

Which ever way is easier I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: The \n inside of a text file will just be read as text by java, so split it into separate lines would be the easiest solution.

Comment: but how would you read 3 lines and store it into one variable.. and then do it again for the next 3 lines storing it in a different variable..

Comment: This question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please explain what you want to achieve and how your data looks like because `\n` seems like result of your attempt to solve real problem, than desired format of your input.

Comment: You would need a counter in your while loop, and everytime through the loop you would add the string to a StringBuilder, and when counter%3 == 0, you would add the StringBuilder to your list, and then reset the StringBuilder.  Then when the loop ends, if the StringBuilder is not empty, you would add that to your list.

Comment: BTW since you seem to be new on Stack Overflow you may not know that to correct your question you can use [[edit]] option placed under your post.

Answer (score 0):

1) "example.txt" contains: `"1. my name is bob \n 2. help you \n 3. Just testing"`

2) You want to interpret it as

```
1. my name is bob
2. help you
3. Just testing
```

3) The buffered reader won't convert "\n" automatically - you must do that in your program.

4) SUGGESTION:

[String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split)  or [String.replace()](http://ttp://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

ADDENDUM - Here's a complete example:

1) Code:

```
package com.so.readlines;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ReadLines {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare our array list
        ArrayList<String> elements = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            // Open file
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("example.txt"));
            // Read next line (with embedded "\n" text string)
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                // ... split "line" into String[] array; add it to "elements" arraylist
                // Collections.addAll(elements, line.split("\\\\n"));
                String[] a = line.split("\\\\n");
                Collections.addAll(elements, a);
            }
            in.close();
            //String check1 = (elements.get( 0));
            //System.out.println("HEYAAA \n" + check1);
            //GUIServer guiServer = new GUIServer();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while reading file line by line:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        // Print contents of array list
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : elements) {
            System.out.println ("elements[" + i++ + "]=" + s);
        }
    }

}
```

2) Example.txt (note extra spaces after "\n"):

```
1. my name is bob \n 2. help you \n 3. Just testing
```

3) Example output:

```
elements[0]=1. my name is bob 
elements[1]= 2. help you 
elements[2]= 3. Just testing
```

'Hope that helps ...